# Doc file corrupted when special charter is being submited in PHPForm

Tags: php, phpword

I have a form where user are filling questionnaire , When they submit special characters The doc created is corrupted

How can I fix this

My code

```
require_once 'src/PhpWord/Autoloader.php';
            \PhpOffice\PhpWord\Autoloader::register();

            if(isset($_POST['submit_docs'])){
            $companyname= $_POST['companyname'];
                        // Creating the new document...
            $phpWord = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\PhpWord();
                        // Adding an empty Section to the document...
            $section = $phpWord->addSection();

                        $html .= '<ul><li>Company Name and Address : '.$_POST["companyname"].' </li></ul>';
                                    \PhpOffice\PhpWord\Shared\Html::addHtml($section, $html);
            $objWriter = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::createWriter($phpWord, 'Word2007');
            $objWriter->save('questionnaire/DMKSA_Questionnaire_'.$arr[0].'.docx');
```

Error

```
Warning: DOMDocument::loadXML(): StartTag: invalid element name in Entity, line: 1 in /home/xxxx/public_html/test/src/PhpWord/Shared/Html.php
```

This happens only when special characters like '<' is being submitted

Any leads on this 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When using the addHtml() function you need to make sure that the content text doesn't have html special characters. This is basically easy to guarantee by using the htmlspecialchars() php function - but unfortunately this leads to next issue (at least it does for me in php 0.12.0), i.e. there is a problem with adding content that contains ampersand characters (&) so you need to do some additional tweaking to get the ampersands working. You could try something like this to parse all the user input values:

```
function fixTextForPhpWord($string)
{
        $text = htmlspecialchars($string);
        $text = str_replace('&', '&amp;', $text);
        return $text;
}
```

so in your case:

```
$html .= '<ul><li>Company Name and Address : ' . fixTextForPhpWord($_POST["companyname"]) . ' </li></ul>'
```